# Rust Diesel left join on multiple conditions

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am having difficulty determining from Diesel's documentation how to express this query with Diesel (without using `raw_sql`):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM budgets AS b 
LEFT JOIN user_budgets AS ub
ON (ub.budget_id = {budget_id} 
    AND ub.user_id = {user_id})
WHERE b.id = {budget_id}
LIMIT 1;
```

`{budget_id}` and `{user_id}` are variable. This is what I've tried:

```rust
let budget = budgets
    .select(budget_fields::all_columns)
    .left_join(user_budgets.on(user_budget_fields::budget_id.eq(budget_id)))
    .left_join(user_budget_fields::user_id.eq(user_id))
    .filter(budget_fields::id.eq(budget_id))
    .first::<Budget>(db_connection)?;
```

but I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `budgets::table: JoinTo<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<user_budgets::columns::user_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/utils/db/budget.rs:46:10
   |
46 |         .left_join(user_budget_fields::user_id.eq(user_id))
   |          ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `JoinTo<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<user_budgets::columns::user_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>>` is not implemented for `budgets::table`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `JoinTo<T>`:
             <budgets::table as JoinTo<JoinOn<Join, On>>>
             <budgets::table as JoinTo<diesel::query_builder::BoxedSelectStatement<'a, QS, ST, DB>>>
             <budgets::table as JoinTo<diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<F, S, D, W, O, L, Of, G>>>
             <budgets::table as JoinTo<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<Left, Right, Kind>>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `JoinTo<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<user_budgets::columns::user_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>>` for `diesel::query_source::joins::Join<budgets::table, user_budgets::table, LeftOuter>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `JoinWithImplicitOnClause<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<user_budgets::columns::user_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>, LeftOuter>` for `diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<budgets::table, user_budgets::table, LeftOuter>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<user_budgets::columns::budget_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>>, query_builder::select_clause::SelectClause<(budgets::columns::id, budgets::columns::is_shared, budgets::columns::is_private, budgets::columns::is_deleted, budgets::columns::name, budgets::columns::description, budgets::columns::start_date, budgets::columns::end_date, budgets::columns::latest_entry_time, budgets::columns::modified_timestamp, budgets::columns::created_timestamp)>>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

I have also tried this:

```rust
let budget = budgets
    .select(budget_fields::all_columns)
    .left_join(
        user_budgets
            .on(user_budget_fields::budget_id.eq(budget_id))
            .and(user_budget_fields::user_id.eq(user_id)),
    )
    .filter(budget_fields::id.eq(budget_id))
    .first::<Budget>(db_connection)?;
```

but I get this error:

```
error[E0599]: the method `and` exists for struct `OnClauseWrapper<user_budgets::table, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<user_budgets::columns::budget_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/utils/db/budget.rs:48:18
    |
48  |                 .and(user_budget_fields::user_id.eq(user_id)),
    |                  ^^^ method cannot be called on `OnClauseWrapper<user_budgets::table, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<user_budgets::columns::budget_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: /Users/tanner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-1.4.8/src/query_source/joins.rs:281:1
    |
281 | pub struct OnClauseWrapper<Source, On> {
    | --------------------------------------
    | |
    | doesn't satisfy `<_ as diesel::Expression>::SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Bool`
    | doesn't satisfy `_: BoolExpressionMethods`
    | doesn't satisfy `_: diesel::Expression`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `<OnClauseWrapper<user_budgets::table, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<user_budgets::columns::budget_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>> as diesel::Expression>::SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Bool`
            which is required by `OnClauseWrapper<user_budgets::table, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<user_budgets::columns::budget_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>>: BoolExpressionMethods`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, your SQL has an `AND`, so you probably want to use [`and`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/expression_methods/trait.BoolExpressionMethods.html#method.and) within `user_budgets.on(...)`?

Comment: Silly me. I tried that and updated the issue.

Comment: The `and` must be *inside* the call to `on`, not after it: `user_budgets.on(user_budget_fields::budget_id.eq(budget_id).and(user_budget_fields::user_id.eq(user_id)))`

Comment: Cool, that worked. I should have been able to figure that out. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely want a single `left_join`. In your second attempt, the error is that the `and` needs to be inside the call to `on`, not after it (the argument to `on` must be the full boolean expression).

```
let budget = budgets
    .select(budget_fields::all_columns)
    .left_join(
        user_budgets.on(
            user_budget_fields::budget_id.eq(budget_id)
            .and(user_budget_fields::user_id.eq(user_id))),
    )
    .filter(budget_fields::id.eq(budget_id))
    .first::<Budget>(db_connection)?;
```